# Adding Ebook Support to a Game

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine, epub

I'm looking to add ebook support (.pdf .txt .epub .mobi .rtf Support) to a game I'm making in Unity using C#. Thing is I really do not know where to start when it comes to this and most of my google searches have gotten me nothing but Ebooks about programming or game development. So I'm hoping someone here would have a good idea where I could start and/or information that would help set me in the right direction.

Comment: You probably won't find a one-shot solution for all those file formats. An easy workaround is to embed a web browser in the game then open the file in the browser. If you want your own custom display control within the game then you'll have a lot more work ahead of you. If you just want to open the file and not embed in the game, just do `Process.Start(...)`

Comment: Hmm, I figured I would have to program it seperately for each file type, though I had hoped I would not have too haha. I'll look into the method you described see if it fits what we are doing. There is plans to embed a web browser so it might just work. Though if not I'd appreciate it if you had any info on any one of the file types listed. If the web browser won't work I have to start somewhere.

Comment: The web browser would definitely work for PDF if you use something like Webkit. Txt would work in there too, and likely Rtf though I've never tried. You'll only really run into problems with the more uncommon Mobi and Epub filetypes.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I will get to work on finding how to implement them now since I will probably need it if the browser won't work for those filetypes

Comment: If you don't mind sum up everything said in an answer post and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to summarize my comments on the OP:

With the least amount of work, embedding a web browser control like Webkit is probably the best option. It should properly read all the common filetypes you mentioned, save for .epub and .mobi. A separate library or control will need to be obtained or coded for those to work. Additionally, if the user already has a default program set up to open those filetypes, you can open them outside of the game with `Process.Start(...)` which is part of the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

If it comes down to you having to code this yourself, a PDF is just drawn graphics on a canvas, txt is just raw text data, and an rtf is text data with some markup to get the formatting right. Coding a component that opens those for you should not be abnormally difficult.